find all zip files and hash the contents of the zip
I have a bunch of zip files in several directories, there are other non-zip files in these directories also.
I am wanting to find all the zip files in the directories such as with find /mnt/sata2 -depth -type f -iname '*.zip'.
Then individually dump the contents from the zip file with unzip -p and then hash the data using md5sum.
Individually I have all the parts, the problem I am having is joining it all together, I've tried the following with limited success, as from what I can tell the command works but for some unknown reason every zip contents is hashing to the same md5 hash, despite the contents being different in each zip.
find /mnt/sata2 -depth -type f -iname '*.zip' -exec bash ./unzip_hash.sh {} \;
for the contents of unzip_hash/sh I have currently
echo "$1";
unzip -p $1 2> /dev/null | md5sum;

This is the output I get from the 2 zip files I put in a test folder.
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /path/to/file1.zip
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  /path/to/file2.zip

I believe -exec is what I should be using as if I change the bash ./unzip_hash/sh to just echo it appears to be running echo for each file found.
I did also try using xargs such as find /mnt/sata2 -depth -type f -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 bash ./unzip_hash.sh but didn't get the results I was expecting.
The output I get from using xargs and the same contents of ./uzip_hash.sh as above is.
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -

From @dave_thompson_085 comment below I have changed the contents of unzip_hash/sh to the following, I had to use print "%q as the filenames inside the zip contain spaces, and I was getting errors otherwise.  However I am still getting the same hash as before.
echo "$1";
unzip -p "$1" printf "%q" $( zipinfo -1 "$1" ) | md5sum;

I am getting an error now caution: filename not matched:
Also this works successfully as in it appears to give me the correct hash as it's not the same as the above.
unzip -p "/path/to/file.zip" | md5sum but this would mean I would have to do it in two stages as in find all the zips and dump the paths to a file, and then run all the paths through the command.

unzip -p extracts the specified entries from the zip file to stdout; you don't specify any entries so it extracts nothing. d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e is the MD5 of (every) nothing; see md5sum </dev/null. Try unzip -p "$1" $(zipinfo -1 "$1") | md5sum . (If you're expecting this to reliably detect different data, you should be aware MD5 has been broken for collision quite practically for two decades, but that's offtopic here; see crypto.SX or security.SX.)

@dave_thompson_085 thanks for the reply and additional information I have since tried that, see updated question but still getting the same hash, also yes I was just using md5 as it makes a hash seemingly quicker than the others so was just using it for testing, I'll use sha256sum once if I ever get this working.

Putting printf %q where you did doesn't work at all, and even if you used it correctly adding quotes or escapes after process substitution (or parameter expansion either) doesn't work. Instead use readarray temp < <(zipinfo -1 "$1"); unzip -p "$1" "${temp[@]}" | md5sum -- IF you want a single hash of all entries in a zip, as I interpreted your Q. If you actually want separate hashes for each entry in a zip, see JayCravens' answer.

If md5sum clobbers every previous value, you have to stat each file individually.It will require a small shell script.
#!/bin/bash

# yad gui selects a directory
input=$(yad --title "Select Directory" --file --directory)

if [[ -z "$input" ]]; then
    echo "Please select a directory."
    exit 1
fi

cd "$input" || { echo "Directory not found."; exit 1; }

echo "Extracting file hashes for zip contents..."

# find zip files recursively in chosen directory
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name "*.zip" > /tmp/zip_paths

readarray -t file_paths < /tmp/zip_paths

for zip_path in "${file_paths[@]}"; do
    temp_dir=$(mktemp -d)

    # extract the zip and create .txt for hashes
    unzip -q "$zip_path" -d "$temp_dir"
    hash_file="$(dirname "$zip_path")/$(basename "$zip_path" .zip).txt"

    # hash each file and append to the .txt file
    (cd "$temp_dir" && find . -type f -exec md5sum {} +) >> "$hash_file"

    # clean up unzipped files
    rm -rf "$temp_dir"
done

echo "Finished!"

exit 0

Save as: hash_zip_contents.sh
Make executable: chmod +x hash_zip_contents.sh
Usage: ./hash_zip_contents.sh
Requires yad for GUI selection of the source directory.  If you don't want yad, remove:
input=$(yad --title "Select Directory" --file --directory)

if [[ -z "$input" ]]; then
    echo "Please select a directory."
    exit 1
fi

cd "$input" || { echo "Directory not found."; exit 1; }

